# Calculate end date in Python given the start date and a varying duration

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I am trying to calculate the end dates of contracts.  I know the start dates and the durations.  The durations vary by contract.
Here is what the dataframe looks like

```
contract_start  Contract Duration
15459   2019-09-01  6
19987   2020-01-01  12
11445   2019-02-01  1
7278    2019-10-01  12
12783   2020-03-01  7
```

I have tried this code

```
testdf['contract_end'] = testdf['contract_start']+ pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(months=testdf['Contract Duration'])
```

It gives me this error:  TypeError: cannot convert the series to class 'int'

I'm guessing I need a way to iterate through the contract duration, but have not been able to figure it out.  Appreciate any help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to enclose the operation into a function and use `df.apply`.

The function could be:

```
def calculateContractEnd(row):
    return row['contract_start'] + pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(months=row['Contract Duration'])
```

Then, we apply this function on `df` to create a new column, say, `'contract_end'` like:

```
df['contract_end'] = df.apply(calculateContractEnd, axis = 1)
```